# Sharing User Inputs via Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

This code solves the problem of how to share user inputs throughout a large application when using dependency injection. To achieve this, I'm using a static (through DI) store and injecting it at those places, where the inputs are needed. In an application without dependency injection, arguments would be passed via constructor, what is not possible when using DI. Alternatives would be to call after injection some `Init`/`Start`/`Load` function.

Please tell me your thoughts and concerns.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8VqsGz

Landmarks:

- Landmark 1: Register all components in DI
- Landmark 1.1: Store is marked as singleton, therefore all injections use the same data
- Landmark 1.2: Store has a readonly interface on business logic side, writable interface is only used in the "ui"
- Landmark 2: Execute user input
- Landmark 3: User inputs and data will be saved in static store
- Landmark 4: Create instance
- Landmark 5: Resolve many IValidation checks
- Landmark 6: Rules will be executed
- Landmark 7: Rule is directly accessing the readonly store to validate the data

Code:

```
// Add reference "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.3"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace sample_di_user_input
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceProvider = ConfigureServices();

            try
            {
                // Landmark 2: Execute user input
                serviceProvider.GetService<SampleInputApplication>().Run();

                // Landmark 4: Create instance 
                serviceProvider.GetService<InputValidationService>().Run();
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null; // Caution! This scopes the singletons

            // Landmark 1: Register all components in DI
            // Landmark 1.1: Store is marked as singleton, therefore all injections use the same data
            // Landmark 1.2: Store has a readonly interface on businesslogic side, writable interface is only used in the "ui"
            var store = new InputDataStore();
            services.AddSingleton<InputDataStore>(x => store);
            services.AddSingleton<IInputDataStore, InputDataStore>(x => store);
            services.AddTransient<SampleInputApplication>();
            services.AddTransient<IValidation, InputAgeValidation>();
            services.AddTransient<IValidation, InputNameValidation>();
            services.AddTransient<InputValidationService>(x =>
            {
                // Landmark 5: Resolve many IValidation checks
                var validationRules = serviceProvider.GetServices<IValidation>();
                return new InputValidationService(validationRules);
            });

            return serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }

    public interface IInputDataStore
    {
        string Name { get; }
        string Age { get; }
    }

    public class InputDataStore : IInputDataStore
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class SampleInputApplication
    {
        private readonly InputDataStore inputDataStore;

        public SampleInputApplication(InputDataStore inputDataStore)
        {
            this.inputDataStore = inputDataStore;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            // Landmark 3: User inputs and data will be saved in static store
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
            inputDataStore.Name = "SampleName";
            // inputDataStore.Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is your age?");
            inputDataStore.Age = "21";
            // inputDataStore.Age = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public interface IValidation
    {
        void Validate();
    }

    public class InputAgeValidation : IValidation
    {
        private readonly IInputDataStore inputDataStore;

        public InputAgeValidation(IInputDataStore inputDataStore)
        {
            this.inputDataStore = inputDataStore;
        }

        public void Validate()
        {
            // Landmark 7: Rule is directly accessing the readonly store to validate the data
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDataStore.Age))
            {
                throw new Exception("No age input");
            }

            if (!int.TryParse(inputDataStore.Age, out int age))
            {
                throw new Exception("Not a valid age number");
            }

            if (age <= 20)
            {
                throw new Exception("Sorry! You are not old enough");
            }
        }
    }

    public class InputNameValidation : IValidation
    {
        private readonly IInputDataStore inputDataStore;

        public InputNameValidation(IInputDataStore inputDataStore)
        {
            this.inputDataStore = inputDataStore;
        }

        public void Validate()
        {
            if (inputDataStore.Name.Length > 5)
            {
                throw new Exception("You are not allowed!");
            }
        }
    }

    public class InputValidationService
    {
        private IEnumerable<IValidation> validationRules;

        public InputValidationService(IEnumerable<IValidation> validationRules)
        {
            this.validationRules = validationRules;
        }

        internal void Run()
        {
            // Landmark 6: Rules will be executed
            foreach (var rule in validationRules)
            {
                rule.Validate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sacrificing channels like method parameters and return values for nothing. Only to force yourself to do a silly thing like making user input a DI service. You should really have a service that can ask user for the input and the caller would then pass it around to those who need it.

Comment: This is perhaps a good way to practice design patterns for a very large, complex application, but if your end goal is really to do something simple -- sometimes simple is better. Stuffing a bunch of code into a method is sometimes more readable and easier to work with. As someone who loves abstractions, I say abstractions aren't necessarily the "right" way to do things. Abstractions are a tradeoff.

Comment: @slepic What is the difference between a "user input DI service" and a "service that can ask user for the input". Apart from one may not be injected...? Also the "caller" of what is not clear. Pass "it" around... do you mean the user input or the user input service?

Comment: @Tom "user input DI service" being data structure holding values inputted from user. "Service that can ask user for the input" would be a service with a method that collects the user input and returns it as a data struct/tuple. The "caller" Is the one who calls the service that collects the input. And "it" referrs to the collected user input data structure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. It was not possible to do the real world example, therefore i choose a simplified codebase, maybe it looks to simple but for concept it should be enough. Sadly, if this is not the right way to handle user inputs with DI, please tell me your solution. I'd love to see some code :) I created another sample how i wouldn't make it https://dotnetfiddle.net/TcE4vq

Comment: In the presented code, you really don't need a DI container. Is your real-world scenario for sure going to need that? I'd say that any ASP.NET Core application should use DI as it is constructor injected into your artifacts seamlessly by the framework, but in other cases it might make sense to create a composition root in `Main` and create your dependencies there.

Comment: @AndreasHassing Thank you. Yes a DI container is in my opinion highly recommended. Its a larger business application with a plugin structure.